# simple timepicker in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, timepicker

what i want to achieve is a dynamic form like this
[image]

"bootstrap/js/local.js"

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#add-entry").click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#items").append('<div>'
        +'<input type="text" id="timepicker">'
        +'<input type="button" value="delete-entry" id="delete-entry"></div>');
});

$('body').on('click','#delete-entry',function(e){

    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});


$("#timepicker").timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });



});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Time Schedule:</label>
                <div id="items">
                    <input type="text" id="timepicker">
                 </div>
                 <input type="button" value="add entry" id="add-entry">
            </div>
```

script files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/local.js"></script>
```

i cant move one because the timepicker is not working

[image]

Comment: What error do you see in console?

Comment: Nobody can help if all you say is **is not working**.  Do you get an error? Does the timepicker come up, but not store the value? There's 100 possible "not working" scenarios.  Further, the `script files` portion of your question would be more useful if you could indicate if you are confident that `local.js` is in fact loading.  Lastly, what does "I can't move one" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since the timepicker input was generated dynamically, you **can't** append event listeners / functions to it this way:

```
$("#timepicker").timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
```

You have to do it the same way that you did it with `#delete-entry` element:

```
$('body').on('click','#delete-entry',function(e){...}
```

This is a bit tricky because you want to run a jQuery UI function on the element, not add an event listener. However, it can be done this way:

```
$('body').on('focus',"#timepicker", function(){
    $(this).timepicker();
});​
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

first of all id="delete-entry" is wrong. id is univocal, use class.

```
$(document).ready()
```

initialize at the end of the page loading
you need to initialize the new input.

For button, you can use

```
$('document').on('click','.delete-entry',function
     alert("click");
);
```